# A little problem with starting Laravel server in docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-8

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
369caac73fe5   php:7.4.6-apache   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   48 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp      web_laravel
```

I have deployed the Laravel `8.x` source code in `web_laravel` docker. I did not get any error while running `composer update` and `php artisan serve`.

```
# php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Jan  20:01:04 2021] PHP 7.4.6 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

But, when I access `192.168.1.xx:8000` in browser, I get the following error.

```
192.168.1.xx refuses to connect
```

I tried to ping `192.168.1.xx`, it works fine. But, I got the following error when using `telnet`.

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.xx 8000
Trying 192.168.1.xx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

It seems that I am having a little problem with starting Laravel server in docker. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

---

As far as I know, each docker has an IP address. So, I have to start the server with the IP address of docker container. However, to avoid errors from **docker's dynamic IP address**, I use `0.0.0.0` instead of the IP address of `web_laravel` docker because `0.0.0.0` means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. I use the following command.

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify where you should run your laravel application ,
by default it's run on 127.0.0.1
try run it by `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.xx`

Comment: I get the error. `Starting Laravel development server: http://192.168.1.xx:8000
[Fri Jan  8 01:53:58 2021] Failed to listen on 192.168.1.xx:8000 (reason: Cannot assign requested address)`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. I vote your post.